MicroShift R9 derailleurs with Shimano Sora levers
 
I have been running a MicroShift R9 2x9 groupset (+ Shimano mechanical disc brakes, BR-M375 I believe) on my gravel bike, which is what it came with when I bought it. Now, I am fairly happy with it, so I wish to keep the group set. The one thing that I want to replace however is the drop bar levers. They run internal brake cabling but external shifting gear cabling, which gets nicely in the way of any handlebar bag bikepacking setup. After some smaller bikepacking trips of basically just squeezing a bag in between the cables, I have decided to go full internal cable setup. 

Now, in order to preserve the rest of the setup I basically limited my options down to Shimano Sora 2x9 levers. Before I start fiddling around with it though, I was wondering if there's anyone who has tried this setup before? I have read that Microshift and Shimano products use the same gear pull ratio, so my guess is it should work more or less fine. However, sharing any experiences would be more than greatly appreciated! 

Cheers

I think, generally speaking, it should work. But what is the worst case scenario? If the Microshift rear derailleur doesn't work well, you would need to obtain a Shimano rear derailleur, any 9sp option (or 8...) from the pre-CUES lineup.
The bigger problem with the Sora shifters is the front derailleur. Shimano have moved to long-arm front derailleurs and the classic short-arm microshift front won't behave the way the Sora shifter expects. The front shifting is unlikely to be acceptable unless you use the correct front mech.
My suggestion is to buy the package, derailleurs and shifters, have it all working properly and enjoy it. Perhaps the microshift group will have some value on the used market so you can recoup some of your extra expense.
